# Add preloader page to all the pages before the main content is shown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website over banking domain.I have made a custom preloader and I want to link that custom preloader to all the pages before the main content is shown.
I searched the Web for tat but no use.
Can u guys pls help me out.

Comment: Please post what you've tried, we're happy to help, but it's near impossible if we don't know what you're using or trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you have created your own custom preloader,  you can use that by following steps:-

1. Put your preloader outside of main website/aplication container.
2. set opacity 0 to main container i will suggest to use some transition. and opacity 1 to preloader, so that you can see preloader only not website.
3. use on window load event of jQuery to make website visible(reverse to step 2) after page/window fully loaded.

example:-

```js
$(window).load(function() { 
  $('.preloader').css({"opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden"});
    $('.main').css({"opacity": "1", "visibility": "visible"});
});
```

```css
.preloader{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  //use position according to your requirment
}

.main{
  opacity:0;
  visibility:vidden;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
<!--your custom preloader will be here-->
</div>

<div class="main">
  <!--your whote website code/HTML will be here-->
</div>
```

Comment: use `<main>` instead of `<div.main>`